# Asus Q550LF Cannot connect to internet in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have just upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 (x64) and I cannt connect to internet, neither ethernet or wifi. On Asus website there are NO drivers for network adapter for Windows 10 so
I tried to install drivers for 8.1 but they dont work. What to do now ??

I have downloaded Intel WiFi Wireless LAN Driver for 8.1 and it says Wireless Hardware is not bound to transport driver

Comment: Why are you trying to use the 8.1 drivers when there are Windows 10 drivers available?

Comment: On asus website there are no Windows 10 drivers for network adapters

Comment: Then you should [edit] your question, which says "On Asus website there are **now** drivers for network adapter for Windows 10. "

Comment: I dont get you, there are NO Windows 10 drivers, for network adapters.

Comment: Read your question again - you said there are "now" drivers. Perhaps you meant to say "no" instead of "now"?

Comment: David I am very sorry, It was I typo. I meant no.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this answer, I can not find any ethernet/wifi drivers on Asus support page for Q550LF and Windows 10.

You can always contact Asus and ask them if they have any beta drivers they are willing to share with you or you can wait until they release them.

I used this page to look for drivers:
http://www.asus.com/supportonly/Q550LF/HelpDesk_Download/

Answer (score 0):

I went to the Intel website for the ASUS Q550LF WIFI driver.

here's the details :

the wifi and bluetooth radio in our Q550 is a 
[Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/wireless/db-ac7260)

Windows 10 users can find it under Device Manager / network devices

The update given by Microsoft at this time, is one version below the latest on the website listed. Don't bother with it.

Go here [Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/wireless/db-ac7260) and find the windows 10 (64 bit or 32 bit depending on what you installed) driver, and run it.

you don't even have to reboot.

Check your wifi after it's installed and it should work.